# Api call to CloudFlare with PHP but without Curl

Tags: php, api, curl, cloudflare

How to make delete api call to cloudflare without CURL in PHP?

My hosting provider doesn't provide me Curl service

---

I am especially interested and wanna make php api call to CloudFlare to Purge All files from cache.

On api page I found

[image]

Then did research and research still research and found a way (maybe) by doing

```
<?php
$data = array (
    "purge_everything"  =>  true
);
$url = "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/MYZONEID/purge_cache";
$opts = array('http' =>
                  array(
                      'method'  => 'DELETE',
                      'header'  => "Content-Type: application/json\r\n" . "X-Auth-Key: MYKEY\r\n" . "X-Auth-Email: MYEMAIL\r\n",
                      'data' => json_encode($data)
                  )
);
$context  = stream_context_create($opts);
$fp = @fopen($url, 'rb', false, $context);
if (!$fp) {
    throw new Exception("Problem with $url, $php_errormsg");
}
$response = @stream_get_contents($fp);
if ($response === false) {
    throw new Exception("Problem reading data from $url, $php_errormsg");
}
return $response;
```

But got error on this

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: Problem with https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/MYZONEID/purge_cache, in /srv/disk11/2444530/www/xxxx.pl/test.php:16 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /srv/disk11/2444530/www/xxxx.pl/test.php on line 16
```

I tried also this way:

```
<?php
$data = array (
    "purge_everything"  =>  true
);
$method = "getCallDetails";
$url = "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/MYZONEID/purge_cache";
$opts = array('http' =>
                  array(
                      'method'  => 'DELETE',
                      'header'  => "Content-Type: application/json\r\n" . "X-Auth-Key: MyKEY\r\n" . "X-Auth-Email: myEMAIL\r\n",
                      'data' => json_encode($data)
                  )
);
$context  = stream_context_create($opts);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

return $result;
```

But good also error, this time:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/MYAPIID/purge_cache): failed to open stream: Network is unreachable in /srv/disk11/2444530/www/xxxx.pl/test.php on line 15
```

And when I get on browser to my `https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/MYAPIID/purge_cache` i see

[image]

Reachable but doesn't work, something is bad here or it is even not possible at all.

So is it event possible to make this thing without CURL? And If yes how to do that?

Comment: What's wrong with actually using cURL?

Comment: @BenM my hosting doesn't provide me Curl

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski dont wanna change my hosting provider. Wanna solve this in php without curl if possible

Comment: My point is changing would most likely be cheaper than wasting time reinventing the wheel

Comment: yeah seriously, contact your webhost customer support, and get them to add curl support, or if they really can't do that, they're a shitty webhost and you should find a new one.

Comment: Don't hide the errors while debugging. Also make file_get_contents to return the response body as string (it might contain more information on problems with the request), set the `ignore_errors` HTTP wrapper option to `true` (default is `false`). You will then always get a string back from `file_get_contents`.

Comment: @hakre I am not hidding errors

Comment: @hakre after adding `'ignore_errors' => true,` i get nothing, blank

Comment: @hakre or not, var_dumped this, got `E:\XAMPP\htdocs\test.php:17:string '{"success":false,"errors":[{"code":1012,"message":"Request must contain one of \"purge_everything\", \"files\", \"tags\", or \"hosts\""}],"messages":[],"result":null}' (length=166)`

Comment: @KrystianPolska: Please try to replace the ` data`  key in the HTTP context options array with `content`, that will be send. See [the PHP Manual entry for all  **HTTP context options**](http://php.net/manual/en/context.http.php) for a description of each, I could not spot a *data* entry, but *content* is used for the request body which sends the data and this error somewhat explains the error message you commented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP HTTP wrapper is not Curl, so you need to translate the `--data` from the Curl command-line switch to the appropriate HTTP context option in PHP.

The entry in PHP is "`content`". Using it instead of "`data`" should do it.

Example:

```
$authKey = "MyKEY";
$authEmail = "myEMAIL";

$zoneId = "MYZONEID";
$endpoint = "purge_cache";

$data = [
    "purge_everything" => true
];

$url = "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/{$zoneId}/{$endpoint}";
$opts = ['http' => [
    'method' => 'DELETE',
    'header' => [
        "Content-Type: application/json",
        "X-Auth-Key: {$authKey}",
        "X-Auth-Email: {$authEmail}",
    ],
    'content' => json_encode($data),
]];
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

# [...] parse response
```

See as well:

- [HTTP context options (PHP Manual)](http://php.net/manual/en/context.http.php)
- [How do I send a POST request with PHP? (SO Q&A)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6609181/367456)
- [HTTP POST from PHP, without cURL (by Wez Furlong)](http://wezfurlong.org/blog/2006/nov/http-post-from-php-without-curl/)

Answer (score -2):

looks like some firewall is preventing file_get_contents from connecting to the outside web. your last code, with file_get_contents, should have worked. contact your webhost customer support, and ask them to unblock your php script from accessing the web. oh, and get them to add curl support, or if they really can't do that, they're a shitty webhost and you should find a new one.

Comment: Tried the same script from my xampp's localhost, the same thing (error)